# Meaning of "most primary relationship"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is the **most primary relationship** between an employee and its employer understood as the *most basic one*, referring to a new work relationship? I do not want it to be understood as the most important or relevant one, just the most basic one.

Comment: If you need to say "most basic" then that is the phrase you should use! If there is some reason why you think you can't use "basic" please add these details. Otherwise I can't really understand your question.  "Most primary" does not seem idiomatic to me.

Comment: (When I read *most primary*, what I hear in my head is *most primal*, which is something quite different.) You can have a relationship that ***is*** primary, but you can't really have one that is ***most*** primary.